# unable to display related product of same subcategory in woocommerce with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i'm working on a site in wordpress and using woocommerce plugin. on my single product page i want to show the related product of same subcategory but unable to do so.

i have a category fall protection with subcategory Harness and Belts and its subcategory is Work Positioning Belts. under that category i have 3 products. i want to show those products as related product.

Here is the code inside my related single-product/related.php

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

$related = $product->get_related( $posts_per_page );

if ( sizeof( $related ) == 0 ) return;

$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
    'no_found_rows'        => 1,
    'posts_per_page'       => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'              => $orderby,
    'post__in'             => $related,
    'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id )
) );

$products = new WP_Query( $args );

$woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

<div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="related products span9">
<div class="hr"></div>
        <h3><?php _e( 'Related Products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best way of doing it but I did this way.

I added a function for getting the products of the same sub category

```
function custom_related_products($product){
    global $woocommerce;
    // Related products are found from category and tag
    $tags_array = array(0);
    $cats_array = array(0);
    // Get tags
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($product->id, 'product_tag');
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) $tags_array[] = $term->term_id;
    // Get categories
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($product->id, 'product_cat');
    foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ){
        $check_for_children = get_categories(array('parent' => $term->term_id, 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'));
        if(empty($check_for_children)){
            $cats_array[] = $term->term_id;
        }
    }
    // Don't bother if none are set
    if ( sizeof($cats_array)==1 && sizeof($tags_array)==1 ) return array();
    // Meta query
    $meta_query = array();
    $meta_query[] = $woocommerce->query->visibility_meta_query();
    $meta_query[] = $woocommerce->query->stock_status_meta_query();
    $meta_query   = array_filter( $meta_query );
    // Get the posts
    $related_posts = get_posts( array(
            'orderby'        => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => $limit,
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'fields'         => 'ids',
            'meta_query'     => $meta_query,
            'tax_query'      => array(
                'relation'      => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
                    'field'        => 'id',
                    'terms'        => $cats_array
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy'     => 'product_tag',
                    'field'        => 'id',
                    'terms'        => $tags_array
                )
            )
        ) );
    $related_posts = array_diff( $related_posts, array( $product->id ), $product->get_upsells() );
    return $related_posts;
}
```

And then in related.php do this

```
global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

if ( sizeof( $related ) == 0 ) return;

$args = apply_filters('woocommerce_product_related_posts', array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'no_found_rows'         => 1,
    'posts_per_page'        => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'               => $orderby,
    'post__in'              => custom_related_products($product),
    'post__not_in'          => array($product->id)
) );

$products = new WP_Query( $args );

$woocommerce_loop['columns']    = $columns;

if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="related products">

        <h2><?php _e( 'Related Products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                <?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php do_action('add_all_to_cart_at_once_for_related_products'); ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </div>

<?php endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

I guess you can call the same logic in related.php to make it simpler but I prefer to keep it separate. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The above works on latest WordPress/WooCommerce (Nov 2014), but you need to override related.php at /wp-content/themes/my-child-theme/woocommerce/single-product/related.php and it needs to look like this:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->exists() ) {
    return;
}

$related = $product->get_related( $posts_per_page );

if ( sizeof( $related ) == 0 ) return;

$args = apply_filters('woocommerce_product_related_posts', array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'no_found_rows'         => 1,
    'posts_per_page'        => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'               => $orderby,
    'post__in'              => custom_related_products($product),
    'post__not_in'          => array($product->id)
) );

$products = new WP_Query( $args );

$woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="related products">

        <h2>You Might Also Like...</h2>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </div>

<?php endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to modify related.php template file.
**PATH: your-theme/woocommerce/single-product/related.php**

Change $args to,

```
$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'no_found_rows' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'post__not_in' => array( $product->id ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $cats_array
        ),
    )
) );
```

where $cats_array is,

```
$cats_array = array(0);
// Get product categories
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat' );

//Select only the category which doesn't have any children
if( sizeof( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $children = get_term_children( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' );
        if ( !sizeof( $children ) )
            $cats_array[] = $term->term_id;
    }
}
```

and remove/comment following lines,

```
$related = $product->get_related( $posts_per_page );
if ( sizeof( $related ) == 0 ) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for way longer than I needed to.

Find my final related.php file. You can paste this over thte generic template file in your child theme.

```
<?php
/**
 * Related Products
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( is_singular('product') ) {
global $post;
// get categories
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) $cats_array[] = $term->term_id;
$query_args = array( 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'no_found_rows' => 1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'product', 'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
'field' => 'id',
'terms' => $cats_array
)));
$r = new WP_Query($query_args);
if ($r->have_posts()) { ?>



    <div class="related products">
        <h2><?php _e( 'Related Products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php while ($r->have_posts()) : $r->the_post(); global $product; ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </div>

<?php

wp_reset_query();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a nice solution for WooCommerce > V3.0.0

Just copy the *single-product/related.php* file from WooCommerce template directory to *wocoomerce/templates/single-product/related.php* in your theme directory and copy paste the following code to the copied related.php file:

```
<?php

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}

global $post, $product;

if (empty($product) || !$product->exists()) {
    return;
}

$subcategories_array = array(0);
$all_categories = wp_get_post_terms($product->id, 'product_cat');
foreach ($all_categories as $category) {
    $children = get_term_children($category->term_id, 'product_cat');
    if (!sizeof($children)) {
    $subcategories_array[] = $category->term_id;
    }
}

if (sizeof($subcategories_array) == 1) {
    return array();
}

$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $subcategories_array
    )
    )
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($wp_query->have_posts()):
    ?>

    <section class="related products">

    <h2><?php esc_html_e('Related products', 'woocommerce'); ?></h2>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php
        global $post, $product;

        $post_object = get_post($product->get_id());

        setup_postdata($GLOBALS['post'] = & $post_object);

        wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
        ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </section>

    <?php
endif;


wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my "related.php" code, where i fetch related products from wp_term_relationships of current product,

this works for me and i applied on 2,3 wordpress websites for related products..

```
 * Related Products
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     3.0.0
 */
global $wpdb;

if(! defined('ABSPATH')) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

$product             = lucian_get_global_variables('product');
$woocommerce_loop    = lucian_get_global_variables('woocommerce_loop');
$lucian_options      = lucian_get_global_variables();



//custom code starts here!!  fetch term_taxonomy_id 
//  $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat' );
// echo '<pre>'; print_r($terms); echo '</pre>'; 
$cats_array = array();
$product_id = $product->id;
$taxonomy_id = "";
// Get categories
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat' );

//Select only the category which doesn't have any children
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
$children = get_term_children( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' );
if ( !sizeof( $children ) )
$cats_array[] = $term->term_id;
$taxonomy_id = $cats_array[0];

}
//custom code Ends here!!



$related = wc_get_related_products( $product->get_id(), $limit = $posts_per_page, $exclude_ids = array() );

if(sizeof($related) == 0) return;

$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
'no_found_rows' => 1,
'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
'orderby' => $orderby,
'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
'field' => 'id',
'terms' => $cats_array
),
)
) );


$products                    = new WP_Query($args);
$woocommerce_loop['name']    = 'related';
$woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters('woocommerce_related_products_columns', $columns);


//custom code starts here!!!
//fetch Product ids throgh taxonomy id
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_term_relationships` WHERE `term_taxonomy_id` = '$taxonomy_id' ");
$tax_id = []; 
$count = 1;

// exclude current post id from given array!!
foreach ( $results as $obj ) : 
if ($obj->object_id != $product_id) {
    if($count <=5)
    {
        array_push($tax_id,$obj->object_id);
    }
    $count++;

}
endforeach;
//custom code Ends here!!!


if ( $tax_id ) : ?>
<div class="widget related_products_widget hv vg-icon">
    <div class="vg-title"><h3><?php
        if(isset($lucian_options['related_icon']) && !empty($lucian_options['related_icon'])) {
            echo '<i class="' .esc_attr($lucian_options['related_icon']) .'"></i>';
        }?><span><?php echo isset($lucian_options['related_title']) ? esc_html($lucian_options['related_title']) : ''; ?></span></h3></div>

    <div class="related products">

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php foreach ( $tax_id as $id ) : ?>

                <?php
                    $post_object = get_post( $id );

                    setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );

                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```